# TFS @Mention not working

Tags: tfs, notifications, mention

HI we are using TFS Version 15.117.26714.0

The problem is whenever there is any mention  (@name) no email is generated against it while after writing @ the names popup but don't get emailed, while other emails are being sent through TFS eg whenever a new workitem is created etc.

Any help/guidance is appreciated

Comment: Where are you using the `@` mention, pull request, commit comments?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@mention` control in pull request discussions, commit comments, changeset comments, and shelveset comments. You can also use the `@mention` control in any text field on the work item form.

To @mention a user you've never selected previously, just continue typing to perform your search against the full directory.

Upon completion of your selection and text entry, your @mention user will receive an email alerting them about the mention.

[image]

More details please refer official tutorial: [Use @mentions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/notifications/at-mentions?view=vsts)

In your case, you could test some other scenarios such as pull request/commit comments and other users if they could receive e-mails. Also check if the mail be blocked as spam in mailbox.

Comment: Mails are received in other cases but not in @mentions so mails are not blocked and not in spam too so there needs to be something else wrong

Comment: @muhammadqasim This is wired, there is not any other extra configuration to make `@mentions` work. And it works well on my side by test the pull request. Could you explain more clearly how your teams  work with the `@mentions`, in a pull request or a comment? Better to include a related screenshot...

Comment: we just add the name with '@' at the start and the name pops out it shows that the name has been written but no mail is generated on it

Comment: @muhammadqasim Where are you adding the name with `@`?  A pull request or 
 work item comment. Not everywhere the `@ ` will generate a mail .

Comment: @muhammadqasim  Please ask the user which be mentioned in the bug workitem to check if  there is  related work in   `http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/_work`   which also helps not miss important work
and user could quickly take action on items where you have been @mentioned.

Comment: We are seeing the same problem.  When we @mention somebody in the Discussion area of a Bug/Task we do not receive any email notifications.  We are running TFS on-premise Version 16.122.27409.2

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT We are still having this issue. Workitem related issues / build notifications are all working (stuff that we can set up). But mentions in pullrequests do not work.